# Never reaching my function call - ReactJs 0.12.0

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, reactjs

I have a jsbin that throws no console errors aside from some show down get request that fails. Aside from that, specific to my code there is no errors, yet it never reaches a specific point.

[The following Jsbin](http://jsbin.com/nudunaqugu/7/edit?html,css,js,output) has an issue. The code works, for all intents and purposes but it doesn't at the same time. If you look at:

**Please note** The following, as far as I can tell, is valid reactjs code.

```
/**
 * A component to display the individual post.
 */
var DisplayPosts = React.createClass({
  render: function() {
    if (this.props.posts === null) {
      return (<div></div>);
    }

    var markDown = new Showdown.converter();

    var post = this.props.posts.slice(0, 4).map(function(post) {
      var content = markDown.makeHtml(post.content)
      return (
        <div>
          <div className="single-post" key={post.id}>
            <h3><a href={"http://writer.aisisplatform.com/blog#post/" + post.title}>{post.title}</a></h3>
            <span dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{__html: content.split(/\s+/).slice(0, 40).join(' ') + '...'}} />
            <hr />
            <div className="float-right">
              <i className="fa fa-comments"></i> {post.comments.length}
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      );
    });

    return (
      <div>{post}</div>
    )
  }
});
```

And place a `console.log` inside the `this.props.posts.slice(0, 4).map(function(post) {` you will never reach there. Place one out side, you reach there. Place one after the block, you reach there. Place one inside - you never reach there.

**What is going on?**

Comment: Your question says ABSOLUTELY nothing about this being react.js.  Please label and explain appropriately.  To someone who doesn't know that's what it is, it looks like entirely illegal scripting.  Put tags on it.  Mention it in the text of the question.  It's highly relevant.

Comment: or you could see the `React.createClass` ....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When `Array.slice()` is called on `[]` it returns `[]`. Then, when `Array.map` is called on `[]` it never calls the iterator function.

So it looks like `this.props.posts` is an empty array in this case.

Comment: And this is because the $.get is failing, which would provide a non-empty array.